# Unique Key Error when exporting Scrapy data to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy

I'm attempting to use the scrapy elasticsearch pipeline (here: https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch) to put data into elasticsearch. however i get the following error, i'm aware that it's related to the ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY value that is currently set at 'url' but i have no idea what it should be set to.

Similar posts on here recommend solutions that involve creating a field for the unique key but i don't understand what this means.

Here's my error message:

```
2015-08-05 11:34:40 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'link': [u'http://www.meetup.com/Search-Meetup-Karlsruhe/events/192357732/'],
 'title': [u'Suchen in der vernetzten Welt']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 70, in process_item
    self.index_item(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 52, in index_item
    local_id = hashlib.sha1(item[uniq_key]).hexdigest()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'url'
```

Comment: Just guessing ... your item has a field with the key 'link' but ElasticSearch seems to expect a item field with the key 'url'. So maybe it's as easy as renaming your 'link' field to 'url'!?

Comment: yes thankyou that helped, although now im using link instead of url its throwing up this error message: TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list

do you have any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Another guess ... probably you get the link by extracting from an xpath. Add a [0] at the end of the statement to get the first item in the list (like response.xpath(...).extract()[0] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Similar posts on here recommend solutions that involve creating a
>   field for the unique key but i don't understand what this means.

Declare a field in your `Item` with the name you configured in the `ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY`.

```
import scrapy

class DemoItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()  # ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY

class DemoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'demo'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):

        demoItem = DemoItem()
        demoItem['url'] = response.url
        yield demoItem
```